# limit of sequence where all entries are less than some $M$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> **Problem $\textbf{12}$**. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers satisfying $x_n < M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Assuming $(x_n)$ converges, show that $\lim x_n < M$. Can you give an example where under our assumptions $\lim x_n = M$? So despite $x_n < M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the limit of $(x_n)$ can be equal to $M$.

This seems too intuitive. every single sequence entry will be less than this $M$ , so if the sequence converges, clearly it has to converge to something less than $M$. Perhaps a proof by contradiction?

Comment: There's something odd in the text. Those $<$ before $lim \: x_n$ should be replaced with $\leq$. Take $-1/n$ as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement isn't quite correct, since it should say that $$\lim x_n \le M$$
(as is implied by the rest of the lines). For a hint at how to prove it, contradiction is useful.

Suppose that the limit $L$ was greater than $M$. By the definition of a limit, the sequence terms have to get *really* close to the limit while still remaining less than $M$. Try to formalize why this is bad, perhaps starting with

$$\epsilon = \frac{L - M}{2}$$

Comment: okay, from what I understand youve given me here:

We let $\lim {x_n} = L$ with $L>M$. then

$|x_n - L | < \epsilon$

and, letting $\epsilon$ be what you said,

$|x_n - L| < \large\frac{L-M}{2}$.

$x_n$ is bounded above by M so

$|M-L| < \large\frac{L-M}{2}$

but this makes no sense. contradiction.

Comment: @terribleatmath Almost;  since $x_n < M$, $$|x_n - L| \ge |M - L| > \epsilon$$ for all $n$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: is this epsilon the distinct epsilon we've chosen?

Comment: @terribleatmath Yes; the inequality follows exactly because $|M - L| > |M - L|/2$.

Comment: Yes I see that, thanks a lot! this is such a great argument!

Comment: @terribleatmath You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\lim \sup x_n\le \sup x_n\le M$. An example where it is equal can be the sequence $x_n:=M(1-e^{-n})\ n\ge 1.$